# 7805 5v regulator outputting 4v

Tags: power-supply, voltage, voltage-regulator, 5v

I'd like to start out that this is my first ever electronics project. I built a 5v power supply from [here](http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/57), using a 7805 5v linear regulator. the only problem is that it is outputting 4v instead of 5v. I want to move on and mount an atmega328 chip, but I'm not sure if I might damage it on accident. Is it safe to go ahead?